# Usando Vundle no VIM

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Recentemente instalei o VIM 8.0 em meu Ubuntu 18.10. Depois, eu instalei via esse tutorial https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim um gerenciador de plugins para o vim.

Existe, portanto, o diretório `~/.vim` em que consta o diretório `/bundle` e o arquivo `.vimrc`, onde o último possui a seguinte configuração:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
" Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Tive alguns problemas e pesquisando eu descobri algumas informações.
Por exemplo, quando digito :scriptnames

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/vim.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/lua.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/perl.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/pod.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/ruby.vim
 27: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim
```

Em que aparetemente está localizando a pasta do .vim

E quando digito `:set runtimepath`:

```
`runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`
```

Eu não sei bem a diferença dos dois comandos, mas independente disso, aparece que ambos estão considerando o diretório do `.vim`,

Problema é que as configurações, por exemplo `set number`, não estão sendo alteradas e nem os comandos de :PlugInstall ou :PluginInstall estão funcionando. Parece que VIM não está lendo o script do `.vimrc`.

O que pode ser? Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido!
Solução bastante simples.

Eu estou realizando as configurações globais do .vimrc no diretório `~/.vim`.
Contudo, as configurações devem ser alteradas no diretório central `$HOME`.

Logo, fiz o seguinte:

Chequei qual era o meu diretório central.

```
    $HOME  
    /home/user
```

Entre no diretório e abri o arquivo .vimrc e apliquei as configurações desejadas.

```
cd /home/user
vim .vimrc
```

Aí é só aplicar as confirgurações.

Atenciosamente,
Arduin